# Converting inerface with delegate from vb to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, interface, vb.net-to-c#

I've got interface:

```
Public Interface ICSIItem

    Sub Initialize()
    Event AnswerValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As NotebookAnswerChangedEventArgs)
    Property DataContext() As Object

End Interface
```

and converter http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

```
public interface ICSIItem
{
    void Initialize();
    event AnswerValueChangedEventHandler AnswerValueChanged;
    delegate void AnswerValueChangedEventHandler(object sender, NotebookAnswerChangedEventArgs e);
    object DataContext { get; set; }
}
```

and resharper says me that delegate cannot be in interface.

This is NotebookAnswerChangedEventArgs class

```
public class NotebookAnswerChangedEventArgs : System.EventArgs
{
    public string NewAnswer;

    public string PreviousAnswer;

    public NotebookAnswerChangedEventArgs(string newAnswer, string previousAnswer) : base()
    {
        this.NewAnswer = newAnswer;
        this.PreviousAnswer = previousAnswer;
    }
}
```

Could you help with this converting and please for better converter site, because that is very poor :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C#, unlike VB.Net, doesn't allow an interface to declare nested types.  This includes delegates.  To fix this simply move the AnswerValueChangedEventHandler delegate outside the interface .

```
public delegate void AnswerValueChangedEventHandler(
  object sender, 
  NotebookAnswerChangedEventArgs e);

public interface ICSIItem {
  void Initialize();
  event AnswerValueChangedEventHandler AnswerValueChanged;
  object DataContext { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: does a interface in VB.net allow to declare nested types? I don't think so but I'm not sure - I guess VB.net knows about the EventHandler delegate - that's all.

Comment: @CKoenig yes. VB.Net does allow for nested type declarations within an interface.

Comment: ok - learned my bit for today ... strange why would you use such a thing ... nevermind - Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface ICSIItem {

   void Initialize();
   event EventHandler<NotebookAnswerChangedEventArgs> AnswerValueChanged;
   object DataContext { get; set; }

}
```

please note - your eventargs supports the use of EventHandler - I think in such cases you should use the EventHandler instead of defining your own delegates anew.

but I don't know any good converters. Why do you convert after all? Just put your VB.net code in a dll and use it from C# - if you write new one do it in C# and convert with time as the need arises.